# Using OpenGL /GLUT how would I detect if two keys are held down at the same time?

Tags: c++, keyboard, glut

Using OpenGL /GLUT how would I detect if two keys, say 'a' and 'j' are held down at the same time?

(This program needs to compile with OSX GCC, Windows GCC, Windows VS2005 so no OS dependent hacks please.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Use `glutIgnoreKeyRepeat` to only get physical keydown/keyup events
2. Use `glutKeyboardFunc` to register a callback listening to keydown events.
3. Use `glutKeyboardUpFunc` to register a callback listening to keyup events.
4. Create a `bool keystates[256]` array to store the state of the keyboard keys.
5. When receiving an event through your keydown callback, set `keystates[key] = true`.
6. When receiving an event through your keyup callback, set `keystates[key] = false`.
7. In your run loop, test if `(keystates['a'] || keystates['A']) && (keystates['j'] || keystates['J'])`.

Look in that direction. Although I haven't tested it, it should work. You might also need `glutSpecialFunc` and `glutSpecialUpFunc` to receive messages for 'special' keys.

Also, be aware that GLUT is really old stuff and that there are much nicer alternatives.

Comment: can you tell more about these nicer alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

by "nicer alternative" if you mean simpler and glut-independant input function then got with GetAsyncKeyState function...

[MSDN - GetAsyncKeyState function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This is Windows-only. And Windows is really old and there are much nicer alternatives.